# Invalidating session state for certain conditions

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an older ASP.NET MVC4 codebase to make some adjustments. I noticed that the application loads an object on each request with information about the user and their billing status. I'd like to move this to session and cache it for approximately 20 minutes (possibly a lot longer) to reduce calls to the database and other APIs.

How can I invalidate the user's session when certain external events happen? In this case, if a customer's billing fails or an admin removes their account I need that session to be required to fetch new data so that the application can log the user out.